# Identity with projector tensor

Tags: renormalization, turbulence

I'm reading [Yakhot and Orszag](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01061452)  article on Renormalization Group Analysis of Turbulence, and I got stuck in a step, which I don't know if it is an identity or if it has some approximation involved.

There is the projector $p_{ij}(\vec{k})$, defined by

$p_{ij}(\vec{k}) = \delta_{ij} - k_i k_j/\vert\vec{k} \vert ^2$

and a tensor $P_{lmn}(\vec{k})$ defined by

$P_{lmn}(\vec{k}) = k_m p_{ln}(\vec{k}) + k_n p_{lm}(\vec{k})$

and eventually on the article, its used that (saying something about expansions up to $\mathcal{O}(k^2)$, even though, I don't think the approximation was on this explicity, was on others terms, I guess)

$P_{n\mu \rho}(\frac{\vec{k}}{2} - \vec{q}) = k_{\mu} p_{n \rho}(\frac{\vec{k}}{2} - \vec{q}) - q_{\rho} p_{n \mu}(\frac{\vec{k}}{2} - \vec{q})$

and I couldn't get this equality with the definitions of $p_{ij}$ and $P_{lmn}$.

I would appreciate any help with this